# Code Was Working - No Changes, Now Not Working (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stumped - this code was working fine - now, it works in the wrong columns. Take column L for example, it's coded to convert the selected cell into Propercase but now it converts to Uppercase. Column I code gets ignored entirely.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Cleanup
Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

   'converts staff codes into uppercase
   If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange.Columns("K")) Is Nothing) And Not Target.Row = 15 Then
        Target.Value2 = UCase$(Target.Value2)
   End If

   'converts Rep Codes into uppercase
     If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange.Columns("J")) Is Nothing) And Not Target.Row = 15 Then
        Target.Value2 = UCase$(Target.Value2)
   End If

   'converts Staff Names into proper case,
   If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange.Columns("L")) Is Nothing) And Not Target.Row = 15 Then
        Target.Value2 = StrConv(Target.Value2, vbProperCase)
   End If

   'converts staff type into capitals.
   If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange.Columns("I")) Is Nothing) And Not Target.Row = 15 Then
         Target.Value2 = UCase$(Target.Value2)
   End If

   'converts store code into uppercase
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("STORE_CODE")) Is Nothing) Then
        Target.Value2 = UCase$(Target.Value2)
   End If

      'converts store name into propercase
   If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("STORE_NAME")) Is Nothing) Then
        Target.Value2 = StrConv(Target.Value2, vbProperCase)
   End If

   'copy pay value one cell over into hidden column
   If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange.Columns("G")) Is Nothing) Then
          Target.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = Target.Value2
          Target.Value2 = ""
   End If
Cleanup:
Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic ' etc..
End Sub
```

Comment: `it's coded to convert the selected cell into Propercase but now it converts to Uppercase.` Search the entire VBA code for `vbUpperCase`. You will get your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Me.UsedRange.Columns("L")` in your code means the `L`th, which is the twelfth, column of your `UsedRange`. If the `UsedRange`starts in column `A`, then this is column `L`. But if the `UsedRange` starts in column `B`, then the twelfth column in `UsedRange` is column `M`.

Example:

```
Sub test()
 Dim oRange As Range

 Set oRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z100")
 MsgBox oRange.Columns("L").Address 'L1:L100

 Set oRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:Z100")
 MsgBox oRange.Columns("L").Address 'M1:M100

End Sub
```

Why the usage of `UsedRange` in your code there?

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, nailed it on the head! I needed different code to be run based on the column the cell was in, and UsedRange worked for me in the past.